# In-memory Job-Explorer definition in Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I was trying to share My in-memory jobRepository to the jobExplorer. But it throws an error as,

Nested exception is

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:
Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy1 implementing
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository,org.
springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised'
to required type
```

Even i tried putting '&' sign before jobRepository when passing to jobExplorer for sharing.But attempt end in vain.

I am using Spring Batch 2.2.1

Is the dependency for jobExplorer is only database not in-memory?

Definition is,

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
        class="com.test.repository.BatchRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="cache" ref="cache" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobOperator" class="test.batch.LauncherTest.TestBatchOperator">
        <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer" />
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer" class="test.batch.LauncherTest.TestBatchExplorerFactoryBean">
        <property name="repositoryFactory" ref="&jobRepository" />
</bean>  


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="com.scb.smartbatch.core.BatchLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!-- To store Batch details -->
    <bean id="jobRegistry" class="com.scb.smartbatch.repository.SmartBatchRegistry" />

    <bean id="jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <!--Runtime cache of batch executions -->
    <bean id="cache" class="com.scb.cache.TCRuntimeCache" />
```

Comment: Can you post your job configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kenston, I have included the definition in My post.

Comment: Did you have `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` directive?

Comment: No I do not have the setting.Can You elaborate its use in spring batch? Thanks

Comment: Are you wiring implementation instead interfaces in your classes?

Comment: Yes I am mentioning the implementation of the resources like repository,registry without using its interface names. Will that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your valuable inputs.

But I used `'&amp;'` before the job repository reference, which allowed me to use it for my job explorer as a shared resource.

problem solved.

kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to wire interface instead of implementation.
Else, probably, you have to add `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">` to create CGLIB-based proxy instead of standard Java-based proxy.
Read [Spring official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-proxying) about that